# Properties of a $B^\ast$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Defining a complex Banach algebra as a $B^\ast$-algebra when it is equipped with an application $\ast:B\to B$ such that for any $x,y\in B$ $$(x+y)^\ast=x^\ast+y^\ast,\quad(xy)^\ast=x^\ast y^\ast,\quad(\alpha x)^\ast=\bar{\alpha}x^\ast,\quad(x^\ast)^\ast=x,\quad\|xx^\ast\|=\|x\|^2$$I read and would like to find a proof that

- a commutative $B^\ast$-algebra is regular, i.e. $\|x^2\|=\|x\|^2$ [edit: I hope I'm right in proving it by noticing that, because of commutativity and since $\|y\|^2=\|yy^\ast\|$, it follows from $\|x\|^4=\|xx^\ast\|^2=\|(xx^\ast)(xx^\ast)^\ast\|=\|x^2(x^2)^\ast\|=\|x^2\|^2$]
- for any $B^\ast$-algebra and for any non-trivial continuous multiplicative linear functional $f_M:B\to\mathbb{C}$ defined on it we have $\forall x\in B\quad \overline{f_M(x)}=f_M(x^\ast)$.

Could anybody help me with a proof or a link to one? $\infty$ thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Suppose that $xx^{\star}=x^{\star}x$ for some $x \in B$. Then $\|x^{2}\|=\|x\|^{2}$ holds because
  $$
     \|x^{2}\|^{2}=\|x^{2}(x^{2})^{\star}\|=\|(xx^{\star})(xx^{\star})\|=\|(xx^{\star})(xx^{\star})^{\star}\|=\|xx^{\star}\|^{2}=\|x\|^{4}.
  $$
- The second part of showing that $\overline{f(x)}=f(x^{\star})$ for all $x$ is equivalent to showing that $f(x)$ is real if $x=x^{\star}$ because, in this case, $x+x^{\star}$ and $i(x-x^{\star})$ are real and, hence,
  $$
           f(x)+f(x^{\star})=\overline{f(x)}+\overline{f(x^{\star})} \\
           if(x)-if(x^{\star})=-i\overline{f(x)}+i\overline{f(x^{\star})}
  $$
  Adding the first to $-i$ times the second then yields $f(x)=\overline{f(x^{\star})}$. I'll carry out this part only in the case where $B$ has a unit $u$, because then one may use the exponential
  $$
                  e^{itx} = u+\frac{(itx)}{1!}+\frac{(itx)^{2}}{2!}+\frac{(itx)^{3}}{3!}+\cdots.
  $$
  This series converges for all complex $t$, but is needed here only for real $t$. The usual exponential properties hold for this series, including $e^{itx}e^{it'x}=e^{i(t+t')x}$ for all $t,\;t'\in\mathbb{R}$. And $e^{itx}e^{-itx}=u$ is the unit. Adjoint is isometric and, therefore, $(e^{itx})^{\star}=e^{-itx^{\star}}$. Finally, because $f$ is continuous and because $f(u)=1$ must hold,
  $$
          f(e^{itx})=f(u)+\frac{(itf(x))}{1!}+\frac{(itf(x))^{2}}{2!}+\frac{(itf(x))^{3}}{3!}+\cdots= e^{itf(x)}.
  $$
  Therefore, if $x=x^{\star}$,
  $$
  \begin{align}
       |e^{itf(x)}|^{2}=|f(e^{itx})|^{2}
                   & \le \|f\|^{2}\|e^{itx}\|^{2} \\
                   & =\|f\|^{2}\|e^{itx}(e^{itx})^{\star}\| \\
                   & =\|f\|^{2}\|e^{itx}e^{-itx}\| \\
                   & =\|f\|^{2}\|u\|.
  \end{align}
  $$
  Because the above is uniformly bounded for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, then it must be that $f(x)$ is real whenever $x=x^{\star}$, which finishes the proof.

Comment: Forgive me for having edited just before you answered, but I'm $\infty$-ly grateful to you: your answer is invaluable as a confirm of my trial to prove the regularity. Thank you so much!

Comment: @DavideZena : That's alright. I have now added a proof of the other part that you need in the case where $B$ has a unit $u$.

Comment: I guess the algebra is intended to be unitary: the book seems to imply that any Banach algebra is by definition. Forgive me: my book talks about such algebras in the text of the exercise only... I don't understand the passages you use to show that it's sufficient to show that $f(x)$ is real for $x=x^\star$: can any $y\in B$ be written as $1/2(x+x^\star+i(x-x^\star))$?

Comment: I find the definition of an exponential in such an algebra very intriguing: I've verified that it converges by using completeness, the inequality $\|xy\|\leq\|x\|y\|$ and the convergence of the compex (or real) series, but I cannot prove to myself that $e^{itx}e^{it'x}=e^{i(t+t')x}$... Thank you so much again!!!

Comment: @DavideZena : If $f(x)$ is real for real $x$, then apply that fact to $x+x^{\star}$ and to $ix-ix^{\star}$ for an arbitrary $x$, both of which satisfy $y^{\star}=y$. Then add them together in the right combination to get $f(x^{\star})=\overline{f(x)}$ for any $x$ (that's what I demonstrated.) The exponential properties are handled by brute force at this point. Use the coefficient identities for the scalar case to get what you want for the operator case.

Comment: Understood: since $x+x^\star$ and $i(x-x^\star)$  are selfadjoint $f(x+x^\star)$ and $f(i(x-x^\star))$ are real. $\infty$ thanks!

Answer (score 3):

B*-algebra is just an old-fashioned name for an abstract C*-algebra. Can you use the [Gelfand–Naimark theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%E2%80%93Naimark_theorem)?

If so, then the first clause follows directly from it as in this case your algebra is isometrically *-isomorphic to the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity $C_0(X)$ defined on some locally compact Hausdorff space $X$. You can use it also to derive the second clause. Indeed, all non-zero multiplicative linear functionals on $C_0(X)$ are just point evaluations for which this is clear.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! The problem is that I cannot use Gel'fand-Najmark theorem because my book uses the above facts precisely to prove it...