# Existence of adjoint operator on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

friends! I read that the algebra $\mathscr{L}(H,H)$ of the bounded operators on a Hilbert space $H$ is a $B^\ast$-algebra in the sense defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/953105/properties-of-a-b-ast-algebra) . I easily verify all the properties except for the facts that for any $A\in\mathscr{L}(H,H)$ the self-adjoint exists in $\mathscr{L}(H,H)$, and that $\forall A\in\mathscr{L}(H,H)\quad \|AA^\ast\|=\|A\|^2$.

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First $\|A\|^{2} \le \|A^{\star}A\|$ holds because
$$
        \|Ax\|^{2}=(Ax,Ax)=(A^{\star}Ax,x) \le \|A^{\star}Ax\|\|x\| \le \|A^{\star}A\|\|x\|^{2}.
$$
Consequently, $\|A\|^{2}\le \|A^{\star}A\|\le \|A^{\star}\|\|A\|$ gives $\|A\|\le \|A^{\star}\|$. Replacing $A$ by $A^{\star}$ in this inequality gives $\|A^{\star}\|\le\|A\|$; hence, $\|A\|=\|A^{\star}\|$. With that,
$$
       \|A\|^{2} \le \|A^{\star}A\| \le \|A^{\star}\|\|A\| = \|A\|^{2} \\
          \implies \|A\|^{2}=\|A^{\star}A\|.
$$

Comment: I heartily thank you! I guess $\|A\|^2\leq\|A^\ast A\|$ follows because $\|A\|^2\leq\sup_{x\ne 0}(\|Ax\|/\|x\|)^2$, but I'm not able to see that... :-(

Comment: If $\|Bx\|\le C\|x\|$ for all $x$, then $\|B\| \le C$.

Comment: So, chosing $C=\sqrt{\|A^\star A\|}$... Another interesting fact is that $\|A\|^2=\|AA^\star\|$ holds in any Euclidean space, as your proof shows. $\infty$ thanks! I edited the title because I meant existence of the "adjoint".

Comment: As to the existence of an operator $A^\star$ such that $\forall x,y\in H\quad\langle Ax,y\rangle=\langle x, A^\star y\rangle$, I've remembered that for any $A\in\mathscr{L}(H,H)$ the operator $\tilde{A^\star}:H^\star\to H^\star$, $f\mapsto f\circ A$ correspond to an application satisfying the adjoint operator definition, cfr. here: http://librarum.org/book/10022/122 , which solves the problem.

Comment: @DavideZena : Yes, I forgot that address that. It's an application of the Riesz Representation theorem. Thanks.